# Build Failed 'duplicate entry: com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/clientlogin/ClientLogin$Response.class

Tags: android, google-maps, android-gradle-plugin, google-api-client, android-build

**Error description**:

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/clientlogin/ClientLogin$Response.class
```

**build.gradle** code here

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jasp.eventapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.8.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.couchbase.lite:couchbase-lite-android:1.4-46'
    //compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'
    //compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-xml:1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.api.client:google-api-client:1.4.1-beta'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-jackson2:1.22.0'
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.5.0-beta.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
}
```

Any version problem in imported libs...?How can I handle this...?I tried by cleaning the project
**Build - > Clean**
after that rebuild, But no effect...Can any one please help me...

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you are using duplicate version of same library, or when you use a library project which has same dependency

```
compile 'com.google.api.client:google-api-client:1.4.1-beta'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-jackson2:1.22.0'
compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.5.0-beta.jar')
```

these **three** looks like same library , removing duplicate version of the library should fix your error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Feign library. Look in the .idea\libraries directory in your project, find the same library with different versions and remove one. It should be help.